# Netty: How to use query string with websocket?

Tags: java, websocket, netty

Here is my code snippets of `ChannelInitializer#initChannel`

```
    ChannelPipeline p = ch.pipeline();

    p.addLast(new HttpServerCodec()         
    .addLast(new HttpObjectAggregator(65536))
    .addLast( new LoggingHandler(LogLevel.INFO))
    .addLast(new WebSocketServerProtocolHandler("/chat"))
    .addLast(new TextWebSocketFrameToChatMessageDecoder())
    .addLast(new UserAccessHandler())
```

It can be accepted via `ws://mydomain/chat`, and now I want to parse query string like this `ws://mydomain/chat?accesskey=hello`

I have looked up `WebSocketServerProtocolHandler`, but I couldn't find how to get query string.

How can I get(or parse) query string? 
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created 3 new classes, copied them.

> WebSocketServerProtocolHandler
>   WebSocketServerProtocolHandshakeHandler
>   WebSocketProtocolHandler

And in copy of WebSocketServerProtocolHandshakeHandler, added these code

```
if(!req.getUri().matches(websocketPath)){
    ctx.fireChannelRead(msg);
    return;
}

String [] splittedUri = req.getUri().split("\\?");
HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

if(splittedUri.length > 1){
    String queryString = splittedUri[1];
    for(String param : queryString.split("&")){
        String [] keyValue = param.split("=");
        if(keyValue != null && keyValue.length >= 2){
            logger.trace("key = {}, value = {}", keyValue[0], keyValue[1]);
            params.put(keyValue[0], keyValue[1]);
        }
    }
}

ctx.channel().attr(AttrKeys.getInstance().params()).set(params);
```

Now I can accpet multiple uri and use query string well.
I think somebody will need this answer.

Comment: I'm very new to netty and facing same issue.
can you please share workable code how did you get URI parameter?

Comment: @MahmoodSanjrani It was too long time ago, so I don't have the code.  I just copied and edited that handlers. and used that handlers instead.

Comment: okay No problem, can you share your experience?

Answer (score 4):

Override method: userEventTriggered and handling event HandshakeComplete.

see [WebSocketServerProtocolHandshakeHandler](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/4.1/codec-http/src/main/java/io/netty/handler/codec/http/websocketx/WebSocketServerProtocolHandshakeHandler.java#L93%20%E2%80%9Csource%E2%80%9D)

**Netty 4.1**

```
public class TextWebSocketFrameToChatMessageDecoder extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<WebSocketFrame> {
    public final static AttributeKey<Map<String,String>> RequestParams = AttributeKey.valueOf("request.params");

    @Override
    public void userEventTriggered(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object evt) throws Exception {
        if(evt instanceof HandshakeComplete){
            HandshakeComplete handshake = (HandshakeComplete)evt;

            //http request header
            HttpHeaders headers = handshake.requestHeaders();

            //http request uri: /chat?accesskey=hello
            String              uri    = handshake.requestUri(); 

            //TODO: parse uri parameters to map ...
            Map<String, String> params ;

            //put to channel context
            ctx.channel().attr(RequestParams).set(params);

        }else{
            ctx.fireUserEventTriggered(evt);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, WebSocketFrame frame) throws Exception {
        //on message
        if (frame instanceof TextWebSocketFrame) {
            Map<String, String> params    = ctx.channel().attr(RequestParams).get();
            String              accesskey = params.get("accesskey");
            System.out.println( accesskey ); //hello
        } else {
            System.out.println( "Unsupported frame type: " + frame.getClass().getName() );
        }        
    }
}
```